# mdDialogue and ngInclude showing current page repeated

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have the following ngInclude, and also tried using a dialog box with the same error. What it's showing is a replica of the current page as if it's calling the current html again. (I'm even getting a 'calling angular twice' error so it definitely seems like that's the problem). I don't know what I'm doing wrong though. Testing through VS on localhost

```
<div ng-show="vm.showUser">
    <ng-include src="'#/userDetailTemplate.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: a fragment can't be used as a include

Comment: I don't know what you mean. userDetailTemplate.html isn't a fragment. I tried it as just one <div> and as a full Doctype html